# C++ array Visual Studio 2010 vs Bloodshed Dev-C++ 4.9.9.2

Tags: c++, visual-studio, arrays, input, dev-c++

This code compiles fine in Bloodshed Dev-C++ 4.9.9.2, but in Visual Studio 2010 I get an error: expression must have a constant value. How do I make an array after the user input about array size without using pointers?

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int size = 1;
    cout << "Input array size ";
    cin >> size;
    int array1[size];
    system("PAUSE");
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use an `std::vector` instead of an array (usually a good idea anyway):

```
std::vector<int> array1(size);
```

In case you care, the difference you're seeing isn't from Dev-C++ itself, it's from gcc/g++. What you're using is a non-standard extension to C++ that g++ happens to implement, but VC++ doesn't.

Comment: And it can be disabled in gcc by adding `-std=c++03` or `-std=c++0x` to the commandline. But these won't work on the GCC in Dev-C++, which is stone-age old and should be burned alive.

Answer (score 0):

The ability to size automatic arrays using a variable is part of C, not part of C++, and is an extension that GCC seems to want to foist on us all. And DevC++ is an unholy piece of cr*p, although it is not at fault here. for a change (this is entirely GCC's doing) - I can't imagine why you (or anyone else) would want to use it.

You should really compile your C++ code with GCC with flags that warn you about stuff like this. I suggest -Wall and -pedantic as a minimum.

Answer (score -1):

Or

`int array1 = new int[size];`

will work aswell I believe (been a month or 3 since I last touched C++)

But indeed, if using C++, go for an std::vector, much more flexible.

Comment: Touch it again before posting here on the subject. Downvote not by me BTW.

Comment: The downote was by me - you need an `int* array1` to store the pointer returned by `new`.